# Tokenizer identifier in Haskell

Tags: haskell

I'm writing this small program basically to identify each input tokens as operator/parenthesis/int.

However, I encountered a problem stating that

```
Not in scope: data constructor `Integer'
```

Here's what I have so far (`Data.Char` only defines `isDigit`, nothing else)

```
import Data.Char (isDigit)
data Token = TPlus | TTimes | TParenLeft | TParenRight | TNumber Integer | TError
    deriving (Show, Eq)


tokenize :: String -> [Token]
tokenize [] = []
tokenize (c:cs)
    | c == '+' = TPlus : tokenize cs
    | c == '*' = TTimes : tokenize cs
    | c == '(' = TParenLeft : tokenize cs
    | c == ')' = TParenRight : tokenize cs
    | isDigit c = TNumber Integer (read c) : tokenize cs
    | otherwise = TError : tokenize cs
```

Some example expected output:

```
*Main> tokenize "( 1 + 2 )"
```

should give

```
[TParenLeft,TNumber 1,TPlus,TNumber 2,TParenRight]
```

and

```
*Main> tokenize "abc"
```

should expect `TError`, but I'm getting

```
[TError,TError,TError]
```

I'd appreciate if anyone could shed some light on these two issues.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For the `Not in scope: data constructor 'Integer'` part, the problem is that you have an extra `Integer` in the line

```
isDigit c = TNumber Integer (read c) : tokenize cs
```

which should be

```
isDigit c = TNumber (read [c]) : tokenize cs
```

The `[c]` part is needed because `read` has type `read :: Read a => String -> a`, and `c` is a `Char`, but `[c]` is a `String` containing only the char `c`.

---

`tokenize "abc"` is returning `[TError, TError, TError]` because of your error treatment policy:

```
| otherwise = TError : tokenize cs
```

This leads us to:

```
tokenize "abc"
-- c = 'a', cs = "bc"
TError : tokenize "bc"
TError : (TError : tokenize "c")
TError : TError : TError : []
[TError, TError, TError]
```

if you want to group all of your errors in a single `TError`, then you should drop all the incorrect input

```
| otherwise = TError : (dropWhile (\o -> o == TError) (tokenize cs))
```

Answer (score 1):

When constructing a `TNumber`, you don't need to (and shouldn't) include the types of each of the constructor's arguments.  Thus, you need to change this:

```
| isDigit c = TNumber Integer (read c) : tokenize cs
```

to this:

```
| isDigit c = TNumber (read c) : tokenize cs
```

Comment: I tried erasing "Integer" and now I'm getting Couldn't match expected type `String' against inferred type `Char'